# Number of paths in hypercube graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have seen that the number of node-disjoint, shortest paths (between two vertices) from x to y in hypercube graph is d(x,y). I was wondering is there a way to find and prove the formula for:

1) Maximum number of mutually node-disjoint paths from x to y ? - regardless of their length (upper bound in graph Qn is n, obviously)

2) The number of all paths from x to y ?

EDIT: For the clarification:
x and y are any arbitrary vertices, all paths should be simple.

Comment: Your question may need some clarification. Are $x$ and $y$ arbitrary vertices, or are you only interested in opposite corners? Secondly, when counting the number of paths from $x$ to $y$, do you assume paths to be simple? Or are you allowed to visit a single vertex multiple times in one path? I have a strong personal preference for the former (a path is always simple; non-simple paths may be referred to as *walks*), but I've seen people use other terminology as well.

Comment: For determining the number of vertex-disjoint paths, you might want to look into [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger's_theorem#Vertex_connectivity).

Comment: I have added the clarification, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is exactly $n$, regardless of the choice of $x$ and $y$. As you said, clearly there cannot be more than $n$, for the start vertex $x$ only has $n$ neighbours. To see that this is attained, we use [Balinski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balinski's_theorem), which asserts that $Q_n$ is $n$-connected. In other words, for any vertex set $S \subseteq V(Q_n)$ containing at most $n - 1$ vertices, the graph $G \setminus S$ remains connected. Now recall that [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger's_theorem#Vertex_connectivity) gives an equivalent definition of [$k$-connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph): a graph is $k$-connected if and only if there are at least $k$ independent paths between any two of its vertices. Thus, putting these two results together shows that there are $n$ independent paths between any two vertices in $Q_n$.

For the second question, I don't think there is a neat answer. To give you an idea of the complexity of some of the paths that can occur: there exists a Hamiltonian path between any pair of vertices that receive a different colour in the canonical 2-colouring of $Q_n$. This is easily proven by induction:

- For $n \leq 2$ you can show this by hand.
- For $n > 2$, you partition the hypercube in two (disjoint) hyperfaces $H_x,H_y$, the first one containing $x$ and the second one containing $y$. Furthermore, you choose another vertex $u$ in the hyperface $H_x$ which has the same colour as $y$ (and therefore a different colour from $x$), and you let $v$ be the unique neighbour of $u$ in the hyperface $H_y$. Note that $v$ is necessarily different from $y$, since $v$ has the same colour as $x$. By the induction hypothesis, we can find a Hamiltonian path from $x$ to $v$ that lies entirely in the hyperface $H_x$. Then we cross over to the dark side and find a Hamiltonian path from $v$ to $y$ that lies entirely in the hyperface $H_y$. (These paths exist since $H_x$ and $H_y$ are isomorphic to $Q_{n-1}$.) This gives us a Hamiltonian path from $x$ to $y$.

Thus, there are many, many paths! Indeed, determining the total number seems to be a very hard problem: even for the special case where $x$ and $y$ are opposing corners of the hypercube, OEIS only knows the answer up to $n = 5$ ([OEIS sequence A059783](http://oeis.org/A059783)).

Note however that the number of *shortest* paths from $x$ to $y$ is easy to determine. I'll leave this as an exercise. ;-)